# Wrong function declaration giving error when inferring on type

Tags: haskell

I have started learning Haskell from [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). In one of the early parts there is an example with binary trees and I started thinking about implementing a remove function and hence got sidetracked to zippers and am now looking at [Zippers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers)

As part of the exercises on the linked wiki page on zippers, I have functions with the following method declarations

```
get :: Node a -> a

put :: a -> Node a -> Node a

retrieveNode :: Thread -> Node a -> Node a

retrieve :: Thread -> Node a -> a
```

Now I try to implement the following function

```
update :: Thread -> Node a -> (a -> a) -> Node a
update t n f = put (f (get (retrieveNode t n)) retrieveNode t n) -- Line 29 referenced
```

Loading this in ghci gives:

```
Prelude> :l theseus.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( theseus.hs, interpreted )

theseus.hs:29:15:
    Couldn't match expected type `Node a'
       against inferred type `Node a1 -> Node a1'
    In the expression:
        put (f (get (retrieveNode t n)) retrieveNode t n)
    In the definition of `update':
        update t n f = put (f (get (retrieveNode t n)) retrieveNode t n)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I read up on the Monomorphism restriction, but couldn't decide if this is relevant for my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the second argument to `put`. From a glance it looks like you just got your parenthesis wrong. Try this.

```
update :: Thread -> Node a -> (a -> a) -> Node a
update t n f = put (f (get (retrieveNode t n))) (retrieveNode t n)
```

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have trouble parenthezising arguments to functions properly, doing in general G(exp1 exp2) where I should be doing G (exp1) (exp2).

Comment: @mb_shart it becomes easier if you remember that `G exp1 exp2` is the right syntax and parentheses are only used to group sub-expressions.